# If $f$ is entire, and bounded by $M$ in $D= \{z \in \mathbb C| |z|<R \}$, and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, prove $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| < \frac{M|z|^2}{R^2} $

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is entire. Let $D= \{z \in \mathbb C| |z|<R \}$, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and there is $M \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $|f(z)|<M$ for every $z \in D$. Prove $\forall z \in D: |f(z)| < \frac{M|z|^2}{R^2} $

Need **hints** only at what I should look at. I can see that for $f(z)= \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, $a_0=a_1=0$. I tried defining the closed disk $\overline D=\{z \in \mathbb C| |z| \leq R \}$ and then using the Cauchy Integral Formula on $C_R$, but I can't use the integral evaluation, because it requieres the maximal value of $f$ on $C_R$, not $D$.

Any **hints** (no full answers please!) will be great!

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function g(z)=Rf(z)/z. This is analytic in the given disc of rad. R and bounded by M. Also g(0)=0. Schwarz Lemma applies to give abs(g(z)<=M.abs(z)/R. This gives the desired result.